# Using the Numlock key as an equals key with XKB

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, numlock

The Numlock key sees little action in today's day and age, yet it's location in the (standard) keyboard layout is quite prominent.

Since I use a lot of spreadsheets, using the keypad for data entry is very convenient, with one caveat: the equal sign is quite hard to reach, when your right hand is on the keypad.

My idea was to re-map Numlock, such that it can act as both, Numlock and equals, with the former accessible through a modifier.

For this purpose I decided to make my own `xkb` keymap, as I tried the same thing with `xmodmap` but I had similarly bad results.

(file name is `pb`)

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    
    name[Group1] = "PB (US intl with level 3 and level 5";
    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";

    include "us(altgr-intl)"

    //              (norm)     NLOCK     AltGr
    key.type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD";
    key <NMLK> { [ KP_Equal, KP_Equal,  Num_Lock, Q ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    include "level5(rctrl_switch)"
};
```

Now, as you can see, I added level 3 and level 5, when I want to expand my custom layout later, but I tested withou it, and it doesn't interfere with Numlock.

The behavior resulting from this is as follows when pressing the Numlock key:

*(numlock is off)*

- <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: '='
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: '='
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: (switches Num lock on)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: 'Q' *(I added this for testing)*

This is alright, printing 'Q' when holding down AltGr and Shift was just to see if I can reach that shift level. However when Num lock is on, the behavior not satisfactory at all:

*(numlock is on)*

- <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: (switches Num lock off)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: (switches Num lock off)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: (switches Num lock off)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numlock</kbd>: (switches Num lock off)

It seems to be impossible to make Num lock behave like a `KP_Equal` key, no matter what I try.

Originally, I wanted pressing <kbd>Numlock</kbd> to print an equal sign, and when holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, to operate Num Lock on and off. Since that didn't seem to be possible, I opted for ISO level 3 (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>), but that doesn't seem to work either.
What I want is that <kbd>Numlock</kbd> prints an equal sign no matter if Num lock is on or off, and switch Num Lock when holding down a mod key (which one, isn't really important to me, preferably <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>).

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that since `<NMLK>` is affected by the state of the `NumLock` modified, but you don't want it to be, it means it's of the wrong type. Try to have this in the symbols section: `key <NMLK> { type = "TWOLEVEL"; symbols[Group1] = [KP_Equal, Num_Lock]; };`

Comment: Having that in the file, I'm getting an error: "Error loading new keyboard description".

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' OK, it seems the file wants `,` between the elements `key <NMLK> {}`, and the map is accepted, but I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I copied the parts separately and added the wrong punctuation. I'm sure what you want is possible because I have something similar with CapsLock, but I can't figure out how I'm doing that… What does the part of the output of `xkbcomp :0 -` corresponding to `key <NMLK>` look like? Does `key <NMLK> { [ KP_Equal, KP_Equal,  Num_Lock, Q, KP_Equal, KP_Equal,  Num_Lock, Q ] };` instead of the 4-element list work any better?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' OK, I did that, now this the behavior: when I have num lock on, and just push <kbd>Numlock</kbd>, it prints the equal sign, but also switches num lock off. I'm quite flabbergasted, this isn't what I was expecting at all.

Comment: btw. same thing when having num lock on, and pressing AltGr + Shift + Numlock, it prints 'Q', and also switches num lock off.

Comment: And what's the output of `xkbcomp :0 - | sed -n '/key <NMLK>/,/}/p'`? For me, with `CAPS`, I get `    key <CAPS> {
        type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1]= [     Mode_switch,       Caps_Lock ]
    };
` and the behavior is that `CAPS` acts as `Caps_Lock` with Alt and as AltGr (`Mode_switch`) without Alt.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' ah forgot that, I'm getting an error: "xkbcomp :0
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError:            Cannot open display ":0"
                  Exiting
"

Comment: `DISPLAY` is set to `:1.0`, when I do `xkbcomp :1.0` I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | …` with the dash as the second argument to `xkbcomp`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' sry, about `xkbcomp` incompetence, here's the output:     key <NMLK> {
        type= "EIGHT_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [        KP_Equal,        KP_Equal,        Num_Lock,               Q,        KP_Equal,        KP_Equal,        Num_Lock,               Q ]
    };

Comment: So you want to arrange for `type` to be something else. `type` determines what modifiers the elements of the `symbols[Group1]` list  correspond to. But even if you can't figure out how to set `type`, you should be able to get something acceptable by rearranging the 8 list elements now.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' ok, so the fact that it does two things (switch off numlock and print the character) is normal? Can you suggest what I should use as `type`, perhaps?

Comment: No, I don't understand that part. It may be due to some other setting but I have no idea what.

Comment: OK, I've tried all the types I could find in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*` none of them change the behavior. When numlock is on, and I press the key, `xev` reports **only** the KP_Equal event, but numlock still goes off. No idea where to go from here.

Comment: Maybe determine which modifier numlock is with `xmodmap -pm` and clear it with `xmodmap -e 'clear Mod6'` (replace 6 by the correct number). On my system `xmodmap -pm` doesn't report a modifier for CapsLock or NumLock, but they do work the way I've set them up with xkb. I don't understand the interactions between xmodmap and xkb.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' `xmodmap -pm` reports `mod2    KP_Equal (0x4d, BadKey (0xcf)`. I cleared mod2, which got rid of Numlock (the key only worked as KP_Equal). I then re-applied my keymap, and it was back to the same old, with `xmodmap -pm` back to reporting `mod2 KP_Equal (0x4d), BadKey (0xcf)`

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this `BadKey`. At a guess it's a symptom of something you need to fix in the xkb code, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

So. If you look at the ouput of `xev', take attention to the **state**,

- If yo keep the keysym <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd> on this key, you will see a state of 10 even when pressing the key for the keysym <kbd>KP_equal</kbd> , without being locked. And because of it, when you are locked, pressing <kbd>KP_Equal</kbd> will unlock you.
- Now you want to get rid of <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd> on this key so it will not generate this pesky state, while still locking on the appropriate layer, it is done like this :

> ```
> replace key <NMLK> {
> type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
> symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Equal, KP_Equal,  Num_Lock, Q ],
> actions[Group1]= [ NoAction(), NoAction(), 
>                    LockMods(modifiers=NumLock), NoAction()
> };
> ```

Take care of the absence of underscore, otherwise it will not work.

- Now you can verify the **state**; it should be ok in any case, but oviously this state doesn't mean anything anymore since you have deleted the <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd> keysym from your map. So you need to find a spare keycode you do not use, and assign him the <kbd>Num_Lock</kbd> keysym. In this example, I'll take the keycode 249

> ```
> replace key <I249> { symbols[Group1]= [ Num_Lock ] };
> ```

Now it should correctly work :)

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still have the effect, that when Num Lock is on, and I press <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>, it prints an equal sign, but also switches off Num Lock. At this point I'm starting to believe it might be a problem with the keyboard controller, or something.

Comment: my bad, I have updated the answer.